# Dİscord.js on Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, discord, discord.js

I was using Windows and now I switched to Linux. When using Windows, I was running my discord.js bot with the "node bot.js" command. I can't run this command on Linux. I created the bot ID again with the command "npm init" and made the test command "node bot.js" but again I get the error. I need your help. (Linux Mint 64 bit)

Error output: `/home/blour/Desktop/ew/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:41`

```
} catch {
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/blour/Desktop/ew/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js:8:11)
```

Comment: That's a syntax error. Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Post the source code of your `Client.js`. Syntax errors are usually easy to spot but for that we need the whole relevant source code. Furthermore if the code is working elsewhere it is an indication that the programming language's syntax has changed so posting your node and npm version on both Linux and Windows is important. You should try to match your Linux node/npm to your Windows one.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your error that you are trying to use a `try/catch` statement, you need to provide the `catch` part of the statement with an `error` parameter:

```js
try {
// Do something
} catch (error) {
// Do something with 'error'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an incomplete try/catch statement. Go to that file and to that line, find a `console.error` in those brackets or something like that and add `(error)` (replace error with the object in `console.error`) just after `catch` and before `{`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an old version of nodejs installed. To reinstall it to a newer one, use:

1. `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev`
4. `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.16.1/install.sh | sh`
5. `source ~/.profile`
6. `nvm install 14.17.4`